# Is it possible to rename item in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

for a repeat in view:

```
ng-repeat="item in list"
```

in some routes item is:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "id": 1
}
```

and in other

```
{
  "value": 
  {
    "name": "john",
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

is it possible to rename item in ng-repeat? may be like:

```
ng-repeat="item as item.value in list"
```

so I can use a common partial view (e.g post-item.html) for all of them.

Comment: What is the purpose for of doing this?

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar I want to use a partial view (e.g post-item.html) in all routes.

Comment: do your data parsing in your controller before handing it into your template.. your controller would check for the `value` property and set it into the item that you'd want to iterate over

Comment: @haxxxton the I had to iterate over items in controller, keeping in mind that Angularjs will iterate again for binding data to view.

Comment: you should rather do it as - ng-repeat="item in list.value", if you want to iterate over the 2nd list

Comment: @Rabi value is a property of items in list not list itself

Comment: can you give me plunker?

Comment: put the ng-repeat into the partial view and just pass the data to it.

Comment: try this ng-repeat="(itemValue, itemText ) in list"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a *ngRepeat* in to rename it

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, item) in i" ng-if="key == 'value'">
    // post item here
  </div>
</div>
```

or using a *filter* instead of *ngIf*.